# bxslider slide show shows last page at first for some reason

Tags: jquery

I am using the bxslider to show the catoon.

```
    <div class="slideBox">
    <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="{{ asset('bundles/acmetop/images/uniq/img_about_comic01.gif')}}" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="{{ asset('bundles/acmetop/images/uniq/img_about_comic02.gif')}}" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="{{ asset('bundles/acmetop/images/uniq/img_about_comic03.gif')}}" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="{{ asset('bundles/acmetop/images/uniq/img_about_comic04.gif')}}" alt=""></li>
    </ul>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
 });
</script>
```

When you load,sometimes first page appears correctly,sometimes the last page appears.

How can I solve this?

I guess it is relevant with the data size of gif.....

{{ asset('bundles/acmetop/images/uniq/img_about_comic04.gif')}} is just the syntax of symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bxslider should always starts with the 1st slide. so it's a bit odd if the last slide is shown first. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/202/)

But still to fix it, try using this option explicitly "startSlide"

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
     startSlide:0
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks,I think it is because of cache of browser,so its really reasonable solution.

Comment: Did you use this solution to solve the problem?  I'm running into this as well and it seems cache related as well.